# Load UIView form in different modes

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, uibutton, xamarin

I have 2 different `UIViewController` setup already.  There is a `UIBarButtonItem` on the parent view and when user clicks on it, it's suppose to load a form (2nd `UIView`).

But on the `UIBarButtonItem`, I have a popover view.  So When they click on the button, popover shows with 6 different `UIButton` and when they select one, the form loads.  Please take a look at the following image to see what I'm talking about.

http://oi58.tinypic.com/f0cbae.jpg

This is because form is different for those 6 different `UIButton`.

How can I load same form in different mode? 
If Button1 is clicked, how would the form know which mode was selected?
I figured I would need parameters for class but couldn't make it work.

============
EDIT:

This is what I tried:

```
public partial class AddAbsence_iPhone : UIViewController {
    public void absenceTypeSelection (string mode) {  
        if (mode == “Button1”) {  
            this.lbl_AbsenceType.Text = “Button1”;  
        }  else if (currentAbsenceType == "Button2”) {
            this.lbl_AbsenceType.Text = "Button2";
        }  else if (currentAbsenceType == "Button3”) {
            this.lbl_AbsenceType.Text = "Button3”;
        }  else if (currentAbsenceType == "Button4”) {
            this.lbl_AbsenceType.Text = "Button4”;
        }  else if (currentAbsenceType == "Button5”) {
            this.lbl_AbsenceType.Text = "Button5”;
        }  else if (currentAbsenceType == "Button6”) {
            this.lbl_AbsenceType.Text = "Button6;
        }  
    }
}
```

and this is how I am adding event to one of the buttons.

```
public partial class Absensehome_iPhone : UIViewController {
AddAbsence_iPhone addAbsence;
    public override void ViewDidLoad () {
        button2.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            this.addAbsence = new AddAbsence_iPhone(this);
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(addAbsence,true);
            addAbsence.absenceTypeSelection("Button2");
        };
    }
}
```

Absencehome_iPhone is the parent view controller.
AddAbsence_iPhone is the form, which I want to show once the button is clicked

When I run this, I get the following error:
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are presenting from a UIPopoverController, you must have a UIViewController subclass. I'm assuming that same class is where you are listening for button taps. With a UIButton, that would be done by registering a listener using:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

So, you could register a different method for each button in that list.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    [self.button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(button2Tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
}
```

If you were generating those buttons programmatically, or there were some other good reason why you couldn't control your flow by registering different handlers, you could register one handler for all the buttons, and check the text of the button that was tapped and passed as the 'sender' parameter:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    [self.button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(aButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
}

- (IBAction)aButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:UIButton.class])
    {
        UIButton* buttonTapped = (UIButton*)sender;
        if ([buttonTapped.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button1"])
        {
            [self button1Tapped];
        }
        else if ([buttonTapped.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button2"])
        {
            [self button2Tapped];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks jeff.  Please take a look at my edit to the original post.  That is what I tried and it gives me error.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure what language you're using, but it does not appear to be Objective-C. Can you reformat your question to include the classes you are using and the important methods?

Comment: I am using Xamarin.iOS for the IDE so I am using C# as my language.  I can "convert" it from Obj-C to C#.  It is 1:1.  I added the info as you requested.  Thanks

Comment: My suggestion was to use the 'sender' parameter to determine which button was hit. 'sender' should be set to the button that was tapped, and you should be able to tell which button it was by the text contained within. Also, if your string comparison is using NSString, you should use the -[NSString isEqualToString:] method for equality comparisons.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I tried it out and it worked out perfectly!

Comment: I accepted the answer but I can not upvote for a little bit because I am a new user. Sorry about that. Thanks again